# YQ: explode simple YAML object into array of objects

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

I'm using Bash and [YQ](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) to do some YAML parsing. My input is a **simple object** that contains **two array properties**. I would like to *explode* both arrays so my simple object is converted into an **array of objects**.

Consider the following YAML:

```yaml
name: a
spaces:
  - alpha
  - beta
envs:
  - dev
  - test
  - prod
```

Now I would like to "explode" both arrays so I get multiple objects:

```yaml
- name: a
  space: alpha
  env: dev
- name: a
  space: alpha
  env: test
- name: a
  space: alpha
  env: prod
- name: a
  space: beta
  env: dev
- name: a
  space: beta
  env: test
- name: a
  space: beta
  env: prod
```

How can I do this with [YQ](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate over the arrays using `[]`, create your final objects using `{…}`, and wrap everthing in array brackets `[…]` again:

```bash
yq '[{"name": .name, "space": .spaces[], "env": .envs[]}]' file.yaml
```

```yaml
- name: a
  space: alpha
  env: dev
- name: a
  space: alpha
  env: test
- name: a
  space: alpha
  env: prod
- name: a
  space: beta
  env: dev
- name: a
  space: beta
  env: test
- name: a
  space: beta
  env: prod
```